# How to create custom ShapeDrawable in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, shapes, shapedrawable

I am working with ShapeDrawables in Android (Kotlin), specifically Circles and Squares that are moving on canvas. But I need other shapes (like triangle, or hexagon), which I failed to create.
I am creating those shapes using:

`val shapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable(RectShape())`

Is there something like `Shape(customTriangleDefinition)`, so I could do the following?

`val shapeDrawable = ShapeDrawable(Shape(customTriangleDefinition))`

I tried to Google it but haven’t find any solution.
Thank you for any responses.

Comment: does this work for you                                                             
           https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jihLJ0oVmGo&ab_channel=Smartherd

Comment: Not really, they are using ImageViews instead of ShapeDrawable. And I need to use it programatically, they have it only as static style.